# Is JSF Service returning error messages a violation of MVC architecture?

Tags: jsf, model-view-controller, message

I am not sure whether I am violating MVC architecture by having my Service return an array of error Strings. The errors are in fact warnings that result from parsing of an excel file that the user has uploaded. There might be multiple of those warnings, and none of them should stop the parsing process. So I believe I cannot possibly use Exceptions. But is there a better way to inform the user about the problems in his/her Excel file than returning an array of error Strings?

The controller:

```
private void handleUpload() {
    ArrayList<String> errors = myService.parseExcel(file);

    for (String error : errors) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error: ", error));
    }
}
```

The service:

```
public ArrayList<String> parseExcel(UploadedFile file) {
    ArrayList<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    // while document not finished, do parsing...
        // if a specific cell incorrect value
              errors.add("Cell at row x, column y has incorrect value");

    return errors;
}
```

Comment: I cant see how you are violating the MVC architecture here (can you even do that to a JSF app?)

Comment: yes, I would like to know that as well (: